# fopen with Internal URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, fopen

We recently changed permissions on a folder (Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS) to accommodate writing text files with PHP.  We can write test files when we use a relative path, but if we attempt to use the $url session variable or the URL itself it fails with (our URL is not public, but on a private internal network):

> PHP Warning:  fopen(txt/newfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\folder\file.php on line 3

Line 3 (URL changed to maintain privacy):

```
$myfile = fopen("http://11.11.11.11/folder/txt/newfile.txt", "w") or die   
("Unable to open file!");
```

whereas this works:

```
$myfile = fopen("txt/newfile.txt", "w") or die   
("Unable to open file!");
```

I checked the php.ini and allow_url_fopen = On.  I can ask the developer to use the relative path, but I would love to know what is going on here and how to use the URL if we would like.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really know how to answer this other than just - because you can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, support for protocols like `http://` or `ftp://` in functions like `fopen` or `file_get_contents` are implemented by so-called ["stream wrappers"](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).

As per the "Options" table for [the `http://` stream wrapper](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php#refsect1-wrappers.http-options) - writing isn't supported.
And while the HTTP protocol does have methods like `PUT` that were designed for writing, in the overwhelming majority of cases, the web is (at least at the HTTP level) read-only to its users.

In addition to that, if you're editing a file on your local machine, there is no good reason whatsoever to involve anything network-related at all, be it for complexity, performance, or security. So just go with the "relative" method - which will go relative to *your current working directory* as opposed to any *URL*.